# debugging sudo -i -u www-data -g www-data env

Tags: linux, sudo

When I run `sudo -i -u www-data -g www-data env`

I get `sudo: unable to change directory to /var/www: No such file or directory`

This must be coming from script somewhere, but I don't know where. How would I find this out and fix it? Is there a standard list of areas to check?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "Must coming from a script" means? The message is clear: The home directory defined (most likely) in `/etc/passwd` for the user `www-data` doesn't exist (see `getent passwd www-data`).

What do you want to do anyway with this command?

Comment: The command is there to make sure the stuff that should be accessible to the server is created with www-data:www-data, the -i is to get the environment loaded properly for rbenv to work. If you see holes in that, your opinion would be appreciated. As for coming from a script, I mean there must be something that is trying to change directory to www-data - that was the issue though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From the sudo man page

> -i, --login
>                    Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such
>                    as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c
>                    option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running
>                    the shell.  The command is run with an environment similar to the one a user would receive at log in.  The Command environment section in
>                    the sudoers(5) manual documents how the -i option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.

So it seems likely that this will be coming from something to do with the www-data account.

I would start by looking in the passwd file for the www-data user  entry and working on from there.